# Title box in Base R plot

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to add a grey box for the title to a base R plot, similar to the ones that come with facet_wrap in ggplot?

I cannot use ggplot for a graphic, but I would like to add the gray title box when combining several plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try a very hackish one.

```
plot(1)
legend(x = c(0.567, 1.432), y = c(1.542015, 1.432), legend="", xpd=T, bg="grey")
mtext("this is a title", side=3, line=1)
```

[image]

More general approach...but still need to find out the ratios to expand the limits manually.

```
xlim = c(1,11)
ylim = c(1,15)
plot(1, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
legend(x = xlim*c(0.84,1.032), y = c(ylim[2]*1.04, ylim[2]*1.16), legend="", xpd=T, bg="grey")
mtext("this is a title", side=3, line=1)
```